# How to set class attributes with __init__ method?

Tags: python, class, oop

I don't get how to access class attributes within class methods. When I assign to variables using `self.something` within a method, it does not access the class attributes.

```
class Dictionary(object):

    words = []

    def __init(self):
        self.words_file = open('words.txt')
        self.words = [x.strip('\n') for x in words_text.readlines()]
        words_file.close()

    def print_list(self):
        print self.words

d = Dictionary()
d.print_list()
```

What I get as out put is `[]`.

I tried not using the `words = []` at the first, then it gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Dictionary' object has no attribute 'words'
```

Comment: `'__init' != '__init__'`, you aren't consistently using `self` (or `words_file`, for that matter), the indentation is off, ...

Comment: What's `words_text` ? Is it supposed to be `self.words_file`?

Comment: The `AttributeError` is because your code never executes your `__init()` function because it needs to be named `__init__()` to be considered the class constructor (and be called in the `d = Dictionary()` statement). If you fix that you will get a `NameError: global name 'words_text' is not defined`. Please post executable code that actually illustrates your question.

Answer (score 1):

The method name should be `__init__`, with two underscores at the end, not `__init`:

```
def __init__(self): #here!
   self.words_file = open('words.txt')
   self.words = [x.strip('\n') for x in words_text.readlines()]
   words_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be closer to your intention:

```
class Dictionary(object):

    def __init__(self):
        with open('words.txt') as words_file:
            self.words = [x.strip('\n') for x in words_file]

    def print_list(self):
        print self.words

d = Dictionary()
d.print_list()
```

You have to be careful with your naming of special methods. They always have to start and end with two underscores. So, it has to be `__init__`. If you use a different name, Python will use the default `__init__()` of `object`. Of course, this does not set `words` as an instance attribute.

This:

```
class Dictionary(object):

    words = []
```

creates a new class attribute. It is shared among all instances. Accessing `words` on `self`:

```
self.words
```

looks in the instance first. If it cannot find the attribute `word` there, it goes to the class. Therefore, you got an empty list for this case.